# Truncate strings in Racket

Tags: string, format, racket

Is there an easy way to truncate strings to a certain width in Racket?

Examples:

```
(truncate "foobar" 3)
-> "foo"
(truncate "foobar" 6)
-> "foobar"
```

I'd also like to replace the last few characters of a truncated string:

```
(truncate "foobar" 4 #:when-truncated "...")
-> "f..."
(truncate "foobar" 10 #:when-truncated "...")
-> "foobar"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `~a` function with the `#:max-width` and `#:limit-marker` keywords to truncate strings.

For example:

```
(~a "foobar" #:max-width 4 #:limit-marker "...")
```

evaluates to `"f..."`.

On the other hand:

```
(~a "foo" #:max-width 4 #:limit-marker "...")
```

evaluates to `"foo"`.

[You can find the documentation for this function here.](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=~a#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._~7ea%29%29)